# Change text inside HTML element using Javascript or anything

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

can some one please help me to change Text only that's inside HTML tags

for example, on my body page when page loaded it shows

```
<td>Hello</td>
```

and i want to change that text only it says "Hello" to "Hi" on ready function No onclick

another example, i know there's on javascript some how it's like, if inside td equals "Hello" then change it to "Hi".

if there's some solution by if...else function that will be better

Thanks.

Comment: you can use the string replace in javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using jQuery:**

```
$(function(){
     $('#tdID').text('Hi');
});
```

Or with pre-condition:

```
$(function(){
    if($('#tdID').text() == 'Hello'){
        $('#tdID').text('Hi');
     }
});
```

**UPDATE:**

For this code to work, you ***must*** have your `td` to be nested within a `tr` which should be nested within a `table`:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="myID">Hello</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

See live example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ynevet/GnQ6h/)

**Full code:**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>jQuery text's attribute demo</title>
</head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    if($('#myID').text() == 'Hello'){
        $('#myID').text('Hi');
    }
});
</script>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="myID">Hello</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: that changes the text o entire td tags that's on that page. but thanks for your answer and if there's some way i can change Text by giving ID on td tag?

Comment: you might wanna mention you using jquery

Comment: OP included jQuery tag in post

Comment: @user3600217 I change the code to select by tag id.

Comment: first, thanks for all your answers. second, can you please look at this code and tell me if there's something wrong? because this code won't work for me

<html>
<head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($('#myID').text() == 'Hello'){
      $('#myID').text('Hi');
     }
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<td id="network">Hello</td>

</body>
</html>

Comment: @user3600217 Yes, change the ID of the `TD` to `myID` (or the ID in the code to `network`) and it should work for you.

Comment: oh sorry. yes i have fixed that too but still the same not working. try it yourself

Comment: @user3600217 See my update in the answer.

Comment: can you please check this : http://jsfiddle.net/LNLt7/

Comment: @user3600217 Yes, you are not using jQuery and onReady wrapper in this example - therefore it won't work.

Comment: hey my friend. can you please update your answer and give me a full code one time? it's really hard for me in php or javascript i'm new learning. pleae update your anser and give me one time full code from <html> to </html>

Comment: oh i got it my friend i'm now using this file 
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js
and ready function and now it's working. thank you very much no one helped me like you did. hank you again been searching for about a week

Comment: i'm not able to vote-up until i have 15 reputation but i'll just as best answer

Answer (score 1):

HTML:
`<td id="myId">Hello</td>`

JS:

```
 document.getElementById("myId").innerHTML="new text";
```

Answer (score 1):

This will change a  from "Hello" to "Hi":

```
$('td').text('Hi');
```

If you give your element an id like so:

`<td id="myTD">Hello</td>`

Then you can change just the text:

```
$('#myTD').text('Hi');
```

This will check each `<td>` for "Hello" and change it to "Hi":

```
$( "td" ).each(function(index) {
  if( $(this).text() == "Hello" ) $(this).text('Hi');
});
```